# R.I.P. Jason David Frank AKA The Green, later the White Power Ranger

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

The actor Jason David Frank, who was probably best known for portraying the Green Ranger in Mighty Morphin Power Rangers has passed away at the age of 49.

R.I.P. Jason :(

<sup>[Daily Mail Newspaper Article: Green Power Ranger is dead at 49](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-11449999/Green-Power-Ranger-dead-49-actor-Jason-David-Frank-played-super-hero-dies-suicide.html)</sup>

Comment: He played his sword-flute like a trumpet as no-one else could. You couldn't even see his lips move. It was amazing.